# What are the new t-sql features sql server 2005?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2000

Where do I find a complete list of new T-SQL features in sql server 2005 comparing with 2000?

A few ones that I know:
Pivot, Output, Try..Catch. Anything else? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a Microsoft reference from Books online:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189465(SQL.90).aspx

It contains Sample database enhancements, tsql data types and some others.  Not the best resource (silly because it's written for SQL Server), but something.

Here is a good resource at SQLServerCentral.com.  Unfortunately you need to join to see the information.  I have been a member for years as there are a lot of good SQL Server articles on the site. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Development/2738/
I would copy some of the information over, but I don't think they would be very happy about that.

Comment: I agreed, it's rather incomplete. Need more details.

Answer (score 2):

My top favourites are:

- VARCHAR(MAX)
- ROW_NUMBER()
- OVER / PARTITION BY (used with ROW_NUMBER() or any aggregate like SUM, COUNT)
- INCLUDED columns in indices
- OUTPUT clause
- TOP on UPDATE & DELETES
- CTE's

Actually.. there's a shitload of good stuff :-)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the biggest new feature in sql2005 for my team has been the ability to mirror databases. I'm a huge fan of that. Not sure of the tsql for it, though, so i'm not really helping you am i?

Answer (score 0):

There is also T-SQL support for Encryption and Key management (which is useful is you want to write functions or stored procedures to encrypt data).

There's a good article [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020131038/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/022107-1.aspx) which shows how to use T-SQL to create keys for encryption.  There's a another similar article on MSDN Blogs [located here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/applisec/archive/2008/06/15/microsoft-sql-server-2005-database-encryption-step-by-step.aspx).

The Books Online documentation for Creating keys (and other T-SQL support for encryption) can be found [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188357(SQL.90).aspx).