# How to work on stored procedures for compatibility

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2000, sql-server-2008-r2

Hi i am using MSSQLSERVER 2000,2005,2008 and 2008R2

i have created SP on 2000 and wanted to run it on higher versions or vise versa say suppose i have created SP on 2008 (i mean SP created on Higher version) and wanted to run it on the lower versions like 2000 or 2005 what things i need to do so that the same code inside the SP or SP will be used over the different different Versions ?
can anybody please help me out on this ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that by "created SP on 2008 and wanted to run it on the lower versions" you mean by coping the procedure's code on 2008 and recreating it on 2000.

If so, it will depend on the T-SQL code you have inside your procedure. If you have a proc on 2008 that does everything that 2000 does, it will work on both versions. But if you have a procedure on 2008 that runs a CTE for example, it wont work on 2000 because CTEs are not supported on that version.

[this](http://www.google.ie/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/0/B/20B90384-F3FE-4331-AA12-FD58E6AB66C2/SQL%2520Server%25202000%2520to%25202008%2520Upgrade%2520White%2520Paper.docx&ei=GEeZT53fDYOA8wPHrdCABg&usg=AFQjCNHREhaRPPZE_tjdjNENilWNKPNpIw) link will download a document that shows the differences

Comment: agreed don't have CTE concept in 2000, so how should we make the code is compatible or SP compatible say suppose i am using date in 200, 2005 but if we used datetime not in 2000 which gives us error.
can you please help me how should we do it.

Comment: Hi, CTE was just an example, there are several things you have to worry about. As you pointed out, date times are different as well. I think the only way to be sure is try creating the proc on 2000

Comment: ok, now i have installed 2000,2005 & 2008 i tried multiple insert in single line which is the feature of 2008 not possible in 2005 and 2000 only solution for this if we used select with union all to insert the multiple values is possible but what if i used the same syntax of multiple value in single line that we are doing in 2008 can we do the backtracking for complexity i mean the multiple value code will run in 2005 & 2000 without making any changes in it.. ?

Answer (score 1):

As a start, don't use CTEs or table variables.

SQL 2005+ is a little more pedantic/compliant about semicolons, so if you write there, it should run on SQL 2000.

For a few lists, see also [What are the new t-sql features sql server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/679821/1352199)

A warning from experience: Microsoft admits to changing query semantics for performance in SQL 2005 and up. See the 6/17/08 11:34AM response by Microsoft:
http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/350485/bug-with-newid-and-table-expressions

For example, I wrote a subquery in SQL 2000 to return a list of valid dates.

```
Select dates.Date, *
From (
    Select Cast(y + '-' + m + '-' + d1 + d2 As smalldatetime) [date]
    From (Select '2007' y Union Select '2008') y,
    (Select '01' m Union Select '02' Union Select '03' Union Select '04' Union Select '05'Union Select '06' Union Select '07' Union Select '08' Union Select '09' Union Select '10' Union Select '11' Union Select '12') m,
    (Select '0' d1 Union Select '1' Union Select '2' Union Select '3') d1,
    (Select '0' d2 Union Select '1' Union Select '2' Union Select '3' Union Select '4' Union Select '5' Union Select '6' Union Select '7' Union Select '8' Union Select '9') d2
    Where IsDate(y + '-' + m + '-' + d1 + d2) = 1
) dates
```

I used that as a subquery to join to a table that had sparse dates so I could build a calendar. While not ideal, I didn't want to build a "dates" table in this case, and it worked.

When we switched to SQL Server 2005, it decided to optimize the "Where IsDate" after the Cast( as smalldatetime). This means it tried to cast something that wasn't a date, and returned an error. I believe I tried nesting the subquery further, so that the Cast was outside the query with IsDate, and it still failed. The solution was to build a temp table or table variable with the results of the subquery, and join that to our sparse table.